# How to use user defined table types in multiple Stored-Procedure?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have created one User Defined Table Type in SQL Server and accessing in two stored procedures.

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[UDType_Sample] AS TABLE(
[Id] [bigint] NULL,
[Id2] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[Id3] [bigint] NOT NULL
```

)

We are using the type in our first StoredProcedure and executed successfully.And if we are using in the second procedure then it taking long time to execute the procedure and it causes some problem in my application regarding this.
Please suggest me about this issue.

Thanks,

Kanna

Comment: You need to show how you are using it in the second stored procedure. They are the same as table variables really. Adding a useful constraint based index to the table definition and/or using `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` may help.

Comment: Thanks Martin Smith it is working....